# Most website visitors don't have Java enabled

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, web-development

So, for the first time ever, I had a look at the "Java Support" dimension in Google Analytics.
According to that, most of our visitors don't seem to have Java enabled (115,844 vs. 7,540 page views). I've read stats that approx. 1-3% of people have Java disabled in their browser, so what's going on on my website? How shall I interpret this data from Google Analytics?!

Our website is based on Javascript and won't work without it. That's why I find it odd that visitors without Java support would spend an average of 2:45 minutes on it. Any explanation or advice is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Java != Javascript

Javascript is a scripting language supported by the overwhelming majority if interactive browsers. Note that I said Interactive browsers - most bots will have extremely limited - if any - support for Javascript

Java is a (semi-compiled) programming language which is largely cross platform but requires additional software to run.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/web-browsers-that-support-java-applets-and-how-to-enable-them/ is an interesting article which talks about Java - and, usefully talks about which browsers support Java. You will see Google Chrome is not among them.